# PHP Imagick: set a gif animation loop to none?

Tags: php, animation, gif, imagick

I've successfully generated an animated gif from a directory of images. I can't figure out how to keep it from looping, though, it just keeps going and going. I think I found the setting in ImageMagick, but I don't see a corresponding way to set it in the Imagick PHP library. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Well, the command line option is `-loop #` where `#` is the number of times to run the whole operation.  Can't find it in IMagick, could try setting it with `setOption()` see if it works.  There are commands to set the delay ticks and ticks per second, but I think it's just been left off.  Could be added to the IMagick extension code fairly easily I think.

Comment: Actually, it is there! See answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took me a while to find it, as missed it going through the IMagick documentation.  But you can set the loop for animated gifs using IMagick.

When I was looking at the code that writes out the Netscape Loop extension in the proper ImageMagick code, it uses an internal variable for the image called `iterations` despite, using `-loop` on the command line.  It uses *iterations* internally the whole time and that is followed through in to the IMagick code.

---

From ImageMagick code: [`coders/gif.c`](http://trac.imagemagick.org/browser/ImageMagick/trunk/coders/gif.c?rev=3)

```
1689        if ((GetPreviousImageInList(image) == (Image *) NULL) &&
1690                (GetNextImageInList(image) != (Image *) NULL) &&
1691                (image->iterations != 1))
1692              {
1693                /*
1694                  Write Netscape Loop extension.
1695                */
1696                (void) LogMagickEvent(CoderEvent,GetMagickModule(),
1697                   "  Writing GIF Extension %s","NETSCAPE2.0");
1698                (void) WriteBlobByte(image,(unsigned char) 0x21);
1699                (void) WriteBlobByte(image,(unsigned char) 0xff);
1700                (void) WriteBlobByte(image,(unsigned char) 0x0b);
1701                (void) WriteBlob(image,11,(unsigned char *) "NETSCAPE2.0");
1702                (void) WriteBlobByte(image,(unsigned char) 0x03);
1703                (void) WriteBlobByte(image,(unsigned char) 0x01);
1704                (void) WriteBlobLSBShort(image,(unsigned short) image->iterations);
1705                (void) WriteBlobByte(image,(unsigned char) 0x00);
1706              }
```

---

See the documentation: [`IMagick::setImageIterations( int $iterations )`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageiterations.php)

Setting `$iterations = 0` makes it loop infinitely.

The delay between frames is set using the tick format I believe, using:

- [`Imagick::setImageDelay ( int $delay )`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagedelay.php) -- where `$delay` is in ticks
- [`Imagick::setImageTicksPerSecond ( int $ticks_per-second )`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagetickspersecond.php).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It turns out that using `IMagick::setImageIterations( int $iterations )` after I've added the frames doesn't keep it from looping, but using it just after I've run `Imagick::newImage ( int $cols , int $rows , mixed $background [, string $format ] )` does the trick.

Comment: @trismi: Remember that apart from when you use `Imagick::writeImages()` or an equivalent multi-image output command, IM has the images all stored separately.  When it goes to write the header, it is probably using the settings on the first image, so the call would have to be upfront on frame 1, like you say.